# How do I map my Union typed GraphQL response Array in React and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, apollo-client

I am using React, Typescript and Apollo Client.

In my React component I query with `useQuery` hook `NODES_TYPE_ONE` or `NODES_TYPE_TWO` based on a value `blockData.myType`. This works fine.

The GraphQL queries looks like:

```
export const NODES_TYPE_ONE = gql`
  query GetNodesOne($customKey: String!) {
    getNodesTypeOne(customKey: $customKey) {
      nodes {
        id
        title
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const NODES_TYPE_TWO = gql`
  query GetNodesTwo($customKey: String!) {
    getNodesTypeTwo(customKey: $customKey) {
      nodes {
        id
        title
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

But how do I type my data in `GqlRes` type?

When I `console.log(data);` I get: two different objects:

```
getNodesTypeOne {
  nodes[// array of objects]
}
```

and

```
getNodesTypeTwo {
  nodes[// array of objects]
}
```

My `GqlRes` type:

```
export type GqlRes = {
  getNodesTypeOne: {
    nodes: NodeTeaser[];
  };
};

/** @jsx jsx */
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import { jsx } from '@emotion/react';

import { Slides } from 'app/components';

import { NODES_TYPE_ONE, NODES_TYPE_TWO } from './MyBlock.gql';
import { Props, GqlRes, NodesArgs } from './MyBlock.types';

const MyBlock = ({ data: blockData, metadata }: Props) => {
  const customKey = metadata.customKey;

  const { data } = useQuery<GqlRes, NodesArgs>(
    blockData.myType === 'type-one' ? NODES_TYPE_ONE : NODES_TYPE_TWO,
    {
      variables: {
        customKey: metadata.customKey || 0,
      },
      errorPolicy: 'all',
      notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
      ssr: false,
    }
  );

  const items =
    data?.getNodesTypeOne.nodes.map((video) => {
      return {
        id: video.uuid,
        type: 'type-one',
        title: title,
      };
    }) || [];


  return <Slides items={items} /> : null;
};

export default MyBlock;
```

Now my items returns only `getNodesTypeOne` but how do I get them both?

**Update:**

I created a union type for `GqlRes`:

```
type GetNodeTypeOne = {
  getNodesTypeOne: {
    nodes: Teaser[];
  };
};

type GetNodeTypeTwo = {
  getNodesTypeTwo: {
    nodes: Teaser[];
  };
};

export type GqlRes = GetNodeTypeOne | GetNodeTypeTwo;
```

But how do I `map` the nodes array now?

**Update 2**

As mention by @Urmzd I tried another approach. Just use multiple `useQuery` hooks:

```
const MyBlock = ({ data: blockData, metadata }: Props) => {
      const customKey = metadata.customKey;
    
      const { data: nodesOne } = useQuery<NodesOneGqlRes, NodesArgs>(NODES_TYPE_ONE,
        {
          variables: {
            customKey: metadata.customKey || 0,
          },
          errorPolicy: 'all',
          notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
          ssr: false,
        }
      );

const { data: nodesTwo } = useQuery<NodesTwoGqlRes, NodesArgs>(NODES_TYPE_TWO,
        {
          variables: {
            customKey: metadata.customKey || 0,
          },
          errorPolicy: 'all',
          notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
          ssr: false,
        }
      );
    
    
      const items =
        data?.// How do I get my nodes in a single variable?? .map((video) => {
          return {
            id: video.uuid,
            type: 'type-one',
            title: title,
          };
        }) || [];
    
    
      return <Slides items={items} /> : null;
    };
    
    export default MyBlock;
```

But how do I `map` my data now, since I have two different GraphQL responses? And what is the best approach in this case?

Comment: Wait, I'm confused. Why do you have two entity containers that contain the exact same entity?

Comment: Also, when someone answers your question, you might want to expand on the thread and not just edit your own post.

Comment: Can you provide the `gql` queries you're making?

Comment: @Urmzd added the query to my question. Thanks

Comment: @Urmzd first try to get my example working. How do I map my union nodes array now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your code directly then depending on the value of `blockData.myType` you're either executing one query or the other and you want to reuse the same `useQuery` hook for this logic. If you want that you'd need to make sure that `GqlRes` is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `getNodesTypeOne` and `getNodesTypeTwo`.

```
// I don't know what NodeType is so I'm just using a string for this example
type NodeType = string

interface GetNodesTypeOne {
    readonly getNodesTypeOne: {
        readonly nodes: NodeType[]
    }
}

interface GetNodesTypeTwo {
    readonly getNodesTypeTwo: {
        readonly nodes: NodeType[]
    }
}

type GqlRes = GetNodesTypeOne | GetNodesTypeTwo

const resultOne:GqlRes = {
  getNodesTypeOne: {
    nodes: [ "test" ]
  }
}

const resultTwo:GqlRes = {
  getNodesTypeTwo: {
    nodes: [ "test" ]
  }
}
```

So this will solve the TypeScript issue. Then later in your code you're doing this:

```
  const items = data?.getNodesTypeOne.nodes.map(...)
```

Since `data` may contain either `getNodesTypeOne` or `getNodesTypeTwo` we need to change this to something else. A quick fix would be to just select the first one that has values:

```
const nodes = "getNodesTypeOne" in data 
    ? data?.getNodesTypeOne?.nodes 
    : data?.getNodesTypeTwo?.nodes
const items = nodes.map(...);
```

Or if you want to use the same condition:

```
const nodes = blockData.myType === 'type-one'
    ? (data as GetNodesTypeOne)?.getNodesTypeOne?.nodes 
    : (data as GetNodesTypeTwo)?.getNodesTypeTwo?.nodes
const items = nodes.map(...);
```

Note that in the second example we need to help TypeScript figure out the specific type by [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) it down using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions). In the first example this is not necessary because TypeScript is smart enough to figure out that the first expression will always result in a `GetNodesTypeOne` and the second expression will always result in a `GetNodesTypeOne`.

---

To answer your second question using the two separate queries:

- Add a new variable `useQueryOne` which is `true` in case we're running query one and `false` in case we're running query two.
- Add `skip` to `useQuery` to run only the appropriate query.
- Add a new variable `nodes` that contains either the results from the first or from the second query (based on the useQueryOne condition)

```
const useQueryOne = blockData.myType === 'type-one';

const { data: nodesOne } = useQuery<NodesOneGqlRes, NodesArgs>(NODES_TYPE_ONE,
    {
        variables: {
            customKey: metadata.customKey || 0,
        },
        errorPolicy: 'all',
        notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
        ssr: false,
        skip: !useQueryOne
    }
);

const { data: nodesTwo } = useQuery<NodesTwoGqlRes, NodesArgs>(NODES_TYPE_TWO,
    {
        variables: {
            customKey: metadata.customKey || 0,
        },
        errorPolicy: 'all',
        notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
        ssr: false,
        skip: useQueryOne
    }
);

const nodes = useQueryOne
    ? nodesOne?.getNodesTypeOne?.nodes
    : nodesTwo?.getNodesTypeTwo?.nodes;
const items = (nodes || []).map(...);
```

Comment: do you have any idea how to map over this union now?

Comment: ok approach is clear, thanks. But I get this typescript error:
 `Property 'getNodesTypesOne' does not exist on type 'GqlRes'.`. Seems like I have no acces to property `getNodesTypesOne` and `getNodesTypesTwo`?

Comment: @meez unfortunately Martin's code is incorrect, he should be using `:` instead of `|`. Also, it's not type-safe. You need to use a type-predicates. Again, all of this can be resolved by splitting the query.

Comment: I agree by the way with splitting the query: I'd personally never try to jam two different queries into the same hook (even if they're very similar). I just answered it with this constraint in mind since the author is looking specifically for a way to achieve this.

Comment: As @Urmzd correctly pointed out my answer was lacking the type narrowing required to satisfy the TypeScript checker, so I added those.

Comment: @MartinDevillers so it's better approach to just create two different `useQuery` hooks?

Comment: Yea I think it's cleaner to keep them separate, even if they're very similar. I've added this second approach to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I should note that your queries are duplicates and hence should be refactored into a single query (unless they're just duplicate namespaces and not values).

Regardless, you can achieve your desired result and in a safer way using [useLazyQuery](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#uselazyquery)

```
const [invokeQuery1, {loading, data, error}] = useLazyQuery<>(...)
const [invokeQuery2, {loading2, data2, error2}] = useLazyQuery<>(...)

// Run the query every time the condition changes.
useEffect(() => { 
  if (condition) {
    invokeQuery1()
  } else {
    invokeQuery2()
  }
}, [condition])

// Return the desired conditional daa
const {nodes} = useMemo(() => {
  return condition ? data?.getNodesTypeOne : data2?.getNodesTypeTwo
} , 
[condition])
```

This also ensures that computation is not done needlessly (and you can invoke your queries based on `events`, as they should be).

-- Edit

Since you're adamant about using the union types (and mapping the data from the source).

Here's one possible, type-safe approach.

```js
const isNodeTypeOne = (t: unknown): t is GetNodeTypeOne => {
  return (t as GetNodeTypeOne).getNodesTypeOne !== undefined;
};

const { nodes } = isNodeTypeOne(data)
  ? data?.getNodesTypeOne
  : data?.getNodesTypeTwo;

const items = nodes.map((val) => {
  // Your mapping here
})
```

If you had different node types, you could also use predicates within the map.

Comment: @meez Updated to answer your other question.

Comment: I updated my question. Thanks

Comment: @meez Look at my first answer (useEffect and useMemo)

Comment: @meez did this solve your problem?